# JQuery fadeOut() Function sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is code..

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo rootpath()?>/show.php",
  data: {
    'url': url,
    'type': 'rawdata'
  },
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

data 'll be loaded on background which i get through alert only that fadeout function some time works.. not always

Comment: during those times that it did now work are you sure that it is getting success from ajax request?i suggest add a `error: function(){}` so you can see if it is really success or fail. also check XHR.

Comment: thanks for comment -guradio

I got data in alert box..... some time it works fine. but when i refresh page several time it will not works continuous..

i check from inspect element  when every thing working then ...
 <div id="default-page-loader"></div>


But when not working

 <div id="default-page-loader">
preloader div here......
</div>

Comment: my question is during those times that it is not working as stated in your question does the ajax request a success?

Comment: yes success on ajax reqst

Comment: are you getting any error when it is not working?in console?

Comment: here inside the fadeOut() why you use **$(this).remove();**?, in fact fadeOut itself hide the targeted element. isn't it?